# capturing photo in landscape mode results rotated image - swift

Tags: ios

I'm using [ImagePicker](https://github.com/hyperoslo/ImagePicker) for my app. When I use photos from gallery it's fine and shows photos correctly, but when I use camera to take landscape photo, result in rotated in 90 degrees. sample from this:

image I'm capturing:

[image]

result:

[image]

Comment: even if it's rotated to other side, what can I do? @Yitzchak

Comment: I don't know, sorry